# how to set route query as useAsyncData watch property

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxt3

I want the useAsyncData to restart when the route query changes

I tried this in my script setup

```
const route = useRoute()
 await useAsyncData(
  'products',
  () => {
    // some code
  },
  {
    watch: [pageNumber, route.query]
  }
)
```

but it won't work. ty in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it works like a regular Vue watcher, you can't watch a property of a reactive object. Standard Vue watcher has a workaround (using a getter) but I'm not sure if `useAsyncData` supports the same. It will probably work if you replace `route.query` with a computed property instead.

```js
const route = useRoute()
const routeQuery = computed(() => route.query)
await useAsyncData(
  'products',
  () => {
    // some code
  },
  {
    watch: [pageNumber, routeQuery]
  }
)
```

Comment: Works. Before, I was using a regular Vue watcher to run my search func (because that was the only working watch I could setup) but was getting strange results (item counts not matching displayed items, etc). Now, properly using useAsyncData's `watch` was the ticket!